# not uploading photo and not showing errors in codeigniter3 framework

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I wrote some code in CodeIgniter that shows all form_validation errors using ajax. Now, I want to insert photo upload function to the form, but when I click submit it does not upload the photo and also does not give an error message, instead it inserts `sheet` into DB, it means isset function doesn't work. Also I don't know how to display  *$this->upload->display_errors()* using ajax. Here is my view:

```
 <div id="messages"></div>

    <?php $attributes = array('class' => 'rex-forms', 'name' => 'continueregistrationform', 'id' => 'continueregistrationform'); ?>
              <?= form_open_multipart('user/submit', $attributes); ?>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="uplimg col-md-5">

            <div style="height:0px;overflow:hidden">
                    <input type="file" id="userfiles" name="userfiles" accept="image/*" onchange="preview_image(event)" />
                </div>

                <button type="button" class="rex-bottom-medium " onclick="chooseFile();">
                    <span class="rex-btn-text">Upload photo</span>
                </button>  
                <script>
                   function chooseFile() {
                      $("#userfiles").click();
                   }
                </script>


                <img id="profph" class="profph" >

                <!-- for showing photo -->

                <script type='text/javascript'>
                function preview_image(event) 
                {
                 var reader = new FileReader();
                 reader.onload = function()
                 {
                  var output = document.getElementById('profph');
                  output.src = reader.result;
                 }
                 reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
                 profph.style.border='2px solid black';
                }
                </script>



            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">


              <div class="row">
                <div  class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div id="name" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?= $instructors['name']; ?>">
                    </div><br>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div id="web" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="web" placeholder="Web-site" value="<?= $instructors['web']; ?>">
                    </div><br>
                </div>
               </div> 

               <div class="row"> 
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div id="tel" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tel" placeholder="Phone" value="<?= $instructors['phone']; ?>">
                    </div><br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div id="address" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Address" value="<?= $instructors['address']; ?>">
                    </div><br>
                </div>
             </div>   
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div id="facebook" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" value="<?= $instructors['fb']; ?>">
                    </div><br>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div id="twitter" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" value="<?= $instructors['twitter']; ?>">
                    </div><br>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div id="youtube" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="youtube" placeholder="Youtube" value="<?= $instructors['youtube']; ?>">
                    </div><br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div id="instagram" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="instagram" placeholder="Instagram" value="<?= $instructors['instagram']; ?>">
                    </div><br>
                </div>
              </div> 

             <!-- CKEditoru bosh saxliyanda validate error gostersin -->
             <script type="text/javascript">
                 CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(){
                      $.each( CKEDITOR.instances, function(instance) {
                                CKEDITOR.instances[instance].on("change",function(e) {
                                  for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances)
                                    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
                                    });
                      });
                });
             </script>

             <div class="row">
                <div  class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div id="insdescription" class="col-md-12 input-group" >
                        <textarea type="text" id="insdescription1" name="insdescription"  class="form-control" rows="5" ><?= $instructors['description']; ?></textarea>
                        <!-- <script>
                            CKEDITOR.replace('insdescription1');
                        </script> -->
                    </div><br><br>
                </div>
              </div>



              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="modal-footer btncolor">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="rex-bottom-medium rex-btn-icon">
                    <span class="rex-btn-text">Submit</span>
                    <span class="rex-btn-text-icon"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i></span>
                </button>  
              </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function submit() {

    //set validation rules

    $validator = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

    $validate_data = array(
        array(
            'field' => 'name',
            'label' => 'name',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[30]'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'web',
            'label' => 'web adress',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_url|prep_url|min_length[3]'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'facebook',
            'label' => 'facebook adress',
            'rules' => 'trim|valid_url|prep_url|min_length[3]'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'twitter',
            'label' => 'twitter adress',
            'rules' => 'trim|valid_url|prep_url|min_length[3]'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'twitter',
            'label' => 'twitter adress',
            'rules' => 'trim|valid_url|prep_url|min_length[3]'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'youtube',
            'label' => 'youtube adress',
            'rules' => 'trim|valid_url|prep_url|min_length[3]'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'instagram',
            'label' => 'instagram adress',
            'rules' => 'trim|valid_url|prep_url|min_length[3]'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'tel',
            'label' => 'telephone number',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|alpha_numeric_spaces|min_length[3]|max_length[30]'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'address',
            'label' => 'adress',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[30]'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'insdescription',
            'label' => 'description',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|min_length[10]'
        )
    );

    $this->form_validation->set_rules($validate_data);
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">', '</p>');

    //validate form input
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        // fails
        $validator['success'] = false;
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $validator['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
        }
    }
    else
    {
            if(isset($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) { 

            $config['upload_path']   = './assets/img/Instructors/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']      = 2048;
            $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;
            $config['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;
            $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);


            if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
                $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $post_image = '';
            } else {
                $datar = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
            }  
        } else {
            $post_image = 'sheet';
        }
        //insert the user registration details into database
        $data = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'web' => $this->input->post('web'),
            'fb' => $this->input->post('facebook'),
            'twitter' => $this->input->post('twitter'),
            'youtube' => $this->input->post('youtube'),
            'instagram' => $this->input->post('instagram'),
            'phone' => $this->input->post('tel'),
            'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
            'description' => $this->input->post('insdescription'),
            'instructor_img' => $post_image
        );


        $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
        // insert form data into database
        if ($this->user_model->updateUser($id, $data)) {
                $validator['success'] = true;
                $validator['messages'] = array();
        }
        else
        {
            // error
            $validator['success'] = false;
            $validator['messages'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">fuckl</div>';
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($validator);
}
```

Here is my model:

```
function updateUser($id,$data){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    return $this->db->update('instructors', $data);
}
```

And here is my ajax file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#continueregistrationform").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
    var form = $(this);


    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response) {
        console.log(response);              
            if(response.success) {                  
                $("#messages").html(response.messages);
                $("#continueregistrationform")[0].reset();
                $(".text-danger").remove();
                $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
                location.href = "http://localhost/edu-center/";

            }
            else {
                $("#messages").html(response.messages);
                $.each(response.messages, function(index, value) {
                    var element = $("#"+index);
                    $(element).parent('div').find('.text-danger').remove();
                    $(element).after(value);

                });
            }
        } // /success
    });  // /ajax

    return false;
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `FormData()` to submit file and input text https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData?

```
$("form#data").submit(function(){

var formData = new FormData(this);

$.ajax({
    url: window.location.pathname,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data)
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});

return false;
});
```

Comment: I made it and it helped!! However instead redirecting it writes SUCESS: TRUE and validations are shown like this https://yadi.sk/i/be6J_ALb3LtPkH

Answer (score 0):

You can check with this in controller:

```
if($_FILES['file_name']['error'] == 0){
   //Upload code
}else{
  //error response
}
```

This code basically when your image file have been break or extension rename at that time it show you error response.

Comment: Use formData like this new FormData('#formId') and use type as POST. If you use serialize image uploading not going to work

Comment: I made it and it helped!! However instead redirecting it writes SUCESS: TRUE and validations are shown like this https://yadi.sk/i/be6J_ALb3LtPkH